# Несколько лет назад город наш посещал поэт, прозаик(,) Такой-то Такой-то

Tags: пунктуация

Доброе утро! Скажите, будьте добры, требуется ли запятая перед именем собственным и почему да/нет.

**Несколько лет назад город наш посещал поэт, прозаик(,) Такой-то Такой-то**

И ещё один вариант:

**Несколько лет назад город наш посещал поэт(,) символист(,) Такой-то Такой-то** (возможен ли вариант не с дефисом — *поэт-символист*, — а именно с запятой?)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть варианты:

1) *Несколько лет назад город наш посещал поэт, прозаик Сергеев.* || Запятая не требуется. Классический вариант.

Примеры Розенталя:
*Учитель военной прогимназии, коллежский регистратор Лев Пустяков обитал рядом с другом своим, **поручиком Леденцовым**.

Действительный член РАН, доктор географических наук, **профессор Е. В. Орлов**.

Заслуженный деятель науки и техники, заведующий кафедрой «Сопротивление материалов», доктор технических наук, **профессор А. И. Соколов**.

Доктор геолого-минералогических наук, профессор, **проректор по научной работе С. Г. Беляев**.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=99

2) *Несколько лет назад город наш посещал поэт, прозаик, [а именно] Сергеев.* || Уточнение, но лучше с тире, потому что до этого была запятая и есть отождествление (можно вставить слово "это"). Стилистически более уместно при одном слове (например: *приезжал поэт, Сергеев*), а то многовато пауз.

> возможен ли вариант не с дефисом

Вполне. "Символист" — самостоятельное слово.
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/символист](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82)

Comment: Вы понимаете, если поставить запятую после "прозаик'", то получается, что Сергиев тоже относится к однородному приложению?

Comment: По смыслу — никак нет. У уточнения такие же права. Но по структуре пунктуации этот вариант реально плох, хотя теория позволяет. Поэтому дальше предлагаю 2 других варианта.